# carregar select option com variável spring

Tags: javascript, html, spring

Tenho uma tabela populada com `<c:foreach>` e em uma das columas tenho um 'ALTERAR' clico nele e carrego as informações do que quero alterar em outra página. Já na outra página, as informações eu queria popular o meu *select option* de acordo com a informação que trouxe via ID.

**EX**: no meu `carregaModal` abaixo eu trago apenas 2 coisas 'Defensivo' e 'Agressivo' eu queria já carregar com um ou outro quando página carregar.

```
${carregaModal.caracteristica
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Característica</label>
    <div>
        <select name="caracteristica" class="form-control">
            <option>Defensivo</option>
            <option>Agressivo</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, muita pesquisa e um pouco de entendimento, para quem teve o mesmo probleminha que eu segue como resolvi.

```
                                             <select name="quadra" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="Rápida" ${carregaModal.quadra == 'Rápida'? 'selected' : '' }>Rápida</option>
                                                <option value="Saibro" ${carregaModal.quadra == 'Saibro'? 'selected' : '' }>Saibro</option>
                                                <option value="Grama" ${carregaModal.quadra == 'Grama'? 'selected' : '' }>Grama</option>
                                            </select>
```

se o seu select estiver num

```
                                            <select name="modalidadeTemp" class="form-control">
                                                <c:forEach items="${listaModalidades}" var="listaModalidades">
                                                    <option value="${listaModalidades.nomeModalidadeTemp}" ${listaModalidades.nomeModalidadeTemp == carregaModal.modalidadeTemp ? 'selected' : ''}>${listaModalidades.nomeModalidadeTemp}</option>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </select>
```